# ActiveAdmin i18n issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I'm trying to i18n some labels on ActiveAdmin but it still not working.

The wrong strings are underlined in the attachment.

[image: non-i18ned strings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put your translations in correct place at translation file?

```
your_lang:
  activerecord:
    models:
      client:
        one: Client
        other: Clients
```

Comment: is an ability to rename columns to show other names for a model?

Comment: your_lang:
  activerecord:
    user:
      phone: "Phone"
      password: "Password"